# Exporting all attributes from a GPX file

Tags: google-earth, arcgis-10.2, gpx

I have a GPX file that i have imported into Google Earth, it looks like this.
[image]

When I try and use the GPX to features tool in ArcGIS, it does not export out all the attributes..
[image]

It seems that GE has access to more data. What do I need to do to export all the attributes shown in the Google Earth popup into my feature class.

Thanks

Comment: The only information you dont get in the output is the speed and heading, the rest is there. Because speed and heading arent part of the official schema, they do not get translated. Without seeing the GPX, I'd guess those attributes are inside some sort of extension GPX element which GE supports. As suggested by an answer, your best bet is to find a conversion tool that supports extension tags.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I view the gpx in Notepad++ there is no extension tag, nor a speed attribute.

Comment: I'm at a loss. All my GPX in GE have a blank popup. My only guess is GE is generating speed and heading (if you arent seeing that in the GPX file), but I don't know why you see that and I dont. I could see GE generating those values on the fly; it's just some basic math to get those extra values when you have 2 points.

Comment: There are no speed and heading attributes in the native data really. There is no need to be, they can be computed by subsequent locations and timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [GPS Babel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) or [QGIS](http://qgis.org).  GPS Babel can convert the GPX to a KML or CSV file, QGIS can open the file for viewing and you can convert it to shapefile or basically any other GIS format.

Comment: I tried with GPS Babel, using the CSV output, the speed field was exported but it was 0. Also tried viewing it with QGIS, same thing.